# How to write regex for domain validation that will trigger pattern error in Angular form

Tags: regex, angular, forms, validation

I am validating a domain field in the form. I am using `Validators.pattern(this.domainPattern)` for doing that. 
I am using below pattern:

```
public domainPattern: string = "^(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]$";
```

It works fine for many cases. But when there is a white space in domain it is not triggering pattern error. What I am missing?

Quick help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Add sample strings that should pass validation, show us what should pass and does not pass, explain your logic for regex.

Comment: google.com  abc.co.in  should pass.

But goo gle.com should not pass

Comment: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactiveform-validation) you can check, how it is behaving currently

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what you really want. I can type `this-s.asjfjff.validdddd-cddddd` for example and tihs is valid. Is this supposed to be valid?

Comment: By the way, your pattern doesn't accept whitespace so if you are matching whitespace there is a problem elsewhere, not in the regex pattern.

Comment: @JackPRead Yes, you are correct. I have customized the regex in my end as per the requirement. My concern was, I was not able to figure out how to stop user to enter multiple valid domain in the one input box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
(?(?<= )(?=[^ ])|^)(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]
```

I just added `(?(?<= )(?=[^ ])|^)`, conditional which checks:

first it checks condition `(?<= )` if what is preceeding is space, if it is, then check if what's after is not a space with `(?=[^ ])`, if the condition fails, then check if we are at the beginning of a string with `^`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5M5RIS/1)

**UPDATE**

OP said:

> I want user to enter just one valid domain name. If user enters "google.com google.com" it should be treated as invalid

Then you could use this pattern

```
^(?!.* .*)(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]$
```

Just added `(?!.* .*)` which checks if there's sapce in following line, if it is, then it won't match anything, as space indicated multiple domain names.

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/5M5RIS/2)

Comment: Thanks for that @Michal. But in my case, I want user to enter just one valid domain name. If user enters "google.com google.com" it should be treated as invalid.

Comment: Thanks @MichalTurczyn. It works as expected. I was struggling for this since yesterday.